# Carregar dados configurados decimal

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu tenho esta função, que funciona, ela trás os dados necessários para aparecer nos input, porém eu queria que trouxesse em decimal, se for 10,00 ele esta aparecendo só o 10
Como posso corrigir?

```
function CarregaEstoque() {
    var idEmpresa = document.getElementById("EmpresaID").value;
    var idProduto = $("#Id").val();
    var url = "/Produto/CarregaEstoque";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { id: idEmpresa, IdProduto: idProduto }
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado > 0) {
                $("#QtdAtual").val(data.qtdAtual);
                $("#QtdMinima").val(data.qtdMinima);
                $("#PrecoCusto").val(data.precoCusto);
                $("#PrecoVenda").val(data.precoVenda);
                $("#CustoMedio").val(data.custoMedio);
                $("#ICMS").val(data.iCMS);
                $("#IPI").val(data.iPI);
                $("#ISS").val(data.iSS);
            }
            else { 
                $("#QtdAtual").val("");
                $("#QtdMinima").val("");
                $("#PrecoCusto").val("");
                $("#PrecoVenda").val("");
                $("#CustoMedio").val("");
                $("#ICMS").val("");
                $("#IPI").val("");
                $("#ISS").val("");
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Aqui é um dos inputs:

```
<input asp-for="PE.PrecoCusto" id="PrecoCusto" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0,00" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando toFixed:

```js
 var numero = 3;
 var numeroMuda = numero.toFixed(2); // coloca duas casas decimais
 alert(numeroMuda); // vai dar 3.00 mas se quiser é só alterar o . por , usando numeroMuda.replace('.', ',');
```